# NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest times out on iOS8

Tags: ios, ios8, nsurlconnection

I have the below code which works perfectly on iOS7 but for some reason times out on iOS8.

```
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error: &error];
```

**Investigation**

How the app works is that on each launch, it sends a synchronous request to the server to see if the account is activated. Thereafter, the rest of the requests for the app to work are asynchronous. After the synchronous request times out, the rest of the asynchronous requests work perfectly.

I suspected it to be due to my web service, but calling it directly from Chrome browser returned within 1 second, and it works fine on iOS7 too.

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25805771/nsurlconnection-timing-out-on-ios8), but I am not using any Basic authentication for my web service, it simply takes a POST parameter and prints out the result on the screen.

When logging my error response, I get the below.

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x16e7d9f0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://appic.sg/vq-websvc/clientGetCustomPiecesForMainScreen.php?merchantID=TEST-SMU2, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://appic.sg/vq-websvc/clientGetCustomPiecesForMainScreen.php?merchantID=TEST-SMU2, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSUnderlyingError=0x16e9a160 "The request timed out."}
```

Comment: There are a million reasons why it could fail. Try  dropping down to a lower lever API (for example, create an `NSURLConnection` and set `self` as the delegate, then print the output of the various `connection:didRecieve...` delegate methods. Also try adding some logging on the server side, chrome will be sending _very_ different HTTP headers which may cause the server to behave differently.

Comment: Hello. I am not sure how do I drop to a lower level API, how do I do that? Logging request on the server side sounds like a good idea. What headers should I print out? I have edited my original post to show the error message I am getting in the response body.

Comment: Look into using a delegate for NSURLConnection. Print all the headers server side, and also log your entire response. Verify you're sending valid data back.